# rails cancan define ability for specific user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have table user and topic in my application. User who create topic has full ability of it and this user can grant ability to other user to access or edit. How can I implement this struct in cancan.
I want something like

```
can? :edit, @topic

can :edit, Topic do |topic|
//get object @topic i pass above, and check current user has ability to edit this topic
end
```

I think about create new table name topic_share with topic_id and user_id. Many-many relation between topic and user. I don't know how to implement it in cancan.

Answer (score 0):

if your have some sort of `creator_id` on the topics table, you can do the following in cancan (assuming that your ability revolves around a user record and creator_id is the id of the user who created the topic and topic belongs_to user)

```
can :edit, Topic, creator_id: user.id
```

Comment: i don't think it'll work in my case. You know many user can access and edit topics if the creator of topic grant them ability. Your solution is only the creator of topic. I think about create new table name topic_share with topic_id and user_id. Many-many relation. I don't know how to implement it in cancan

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a direct answer, but you might want to take a look at this gem I created : https://github.com/intrepidd/rails-canhaz

It allows easily to create permissions between any model.